# Removing x-axis label from dendrogram in r

Tags: r, plot, hclust

I use xlab="" to suppress the x-label but still get a 'sub-x-label' in my dendrogram. How can I remove this and remove any extra space under the dendrogram?

```
require(graphics)

hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
plot(hc,xlab="")
```

[image]

Comment: use `plot(hc,xlab=NA, sub=NA)`, as explained in the help page for `?plot.hclust`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To remove the subtitle use the following:

```
plot(hc, xlab="", sub="")
```

To remove the bottom margin (see `?par` for details):

```
par(mar=c(0, 4, 4, 2)) # c(bottom, left, top, right)
plot(hc, xlab="", sub="")
```

Comment: Thank you. The subtitle is aded automatically and I just didn't realise it was a subtitle.

Comment: give this man some bacon (or chocolate, or whatever else he fancies), for he solved my struggling of a very long time (more than I will be ever happy to admit). 

Thank you, kind stranger!!!

Answer (score 8):

May be  `plot(hc,xlab='', sub="")` removes it.

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
op <- par(mar = c(2,4,4,2) + 0.1))
plot(hc, xlab = "", sub = "")
par(op)
```

The first `par()` line stores the current settings and then sets the margin to be 2 lines bottom, 4 on the left and top and 2 lines on the right (plus a bit). Then we plot setting an empty string for the *sub*title via argument `sub`. Finally we set the parameters back to what they were before the first line.

I left a bit of room on the bottom margin as I'm not sure how far the labels can hand down. Change the first `2` in `mar = c(2,4,4,2)` to something smaller if you want less space down the bottom.